# How to run a block of code for a certain amount of time in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So I have a method that draws squares and at a random chance, it will draw only triangles for 5 seconds, then return to drawing squares. How do I run the `drawTriangle()` continuously for a certain amount of time, then break out of it?

```
drawShape(){  
   drawSquare();  
   if (arc4random_uniform(50) == 0){
      for 5 seconds{ << how do I implement that part?
         stopDrawSquare();
         drawTriangle();
      }
   }
}

SKAction *draw = [SKAction sequence:@[
                    [SKAction waitForDuration:1 withRange:1],
                    [SKAction performSelector:@selector(drawShape) onTarget:self]
                 ]];              
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:draw] withKey:@"drawShape"];
```

Comment: use self perform selector after delay.

Comment: You might be best moving everything over to the SKScene's update loop and calculating time and executing code there. Otherwise I would build everything into SKActions. Using SKActions you could get rid of repeatForever and instead re run the correct action in your method (or customAction)

Comment: Have some sort of timer toggle a flag.  Sit in a loop drawing until the flag toggles.  (You do need to worry about concurrency/synchronization with the flag, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 ivars:

```
BOOL ready;
BOOL drawTriangle;
```

Set ready to default true and drawTriangle to default false.

Add this code to your update method (or wherever you decide it should go)

```
if(ready == true) {
    if (arc4random_uniform(50) == 0) {
        drawTriangle = true;
        ready = false;
        SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:5.0];
        SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            ready = true;
        }];
        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait0, block0]]];
    } else {
        drawTriangle = false;
    }
}

if(drawTriangle == true) {
    NSLog(@"draw triangle");
} else {
    NSLog(@"draw square");
}
```